# Autodesk forge about how to calculate global offset

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to do some model operations in C# that require the use of global offset, so I download the [metadata.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeFgP.png) file to [read some of the key information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsK6O.png)

[I have read this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260292/how-does-forge-viewer-calculate-globaloffset/66435367#66435367)

I thought there was an error in this article at first, but when I verified it in webview, I found that there was no problem.

But the bounding box recorded in the file I [downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTdDT.png) is inconsistent with [him](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXGoF.png).

I think it is because I downloaded a wrong file? This is the [code for the file I downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFIxd.png).

Comment: Hi Roc, not sure what you're trying to do. do you mean the calculated bbox does not match with the one from metadata?

Comment: Yes, I tried to download the svf model, but the resulting model's bounding box did not match the bounding box on the viewer

Comment: Have you tried these 2 answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260292/how-does-forge-viewer-calculate-globaloffset/66435367#66435367

Comment: Yes, I tried both answers. Both answers are correct. The problem occurred when I tried to download metadata, and the bounding box in the metadata downloaded was different from `svfmodel.getData().metadata["world bounding box"]`. They are the same in most models, except for the particular one where I found the problem

Comment: please make sure you're not comparing SVF and SVF2 formats.

Comment: I have verified that all models are svf1, not svf2, and only this model has a different bounding box

Comment: Can you please send the file, we'll test on our end. aps(dot)help@autodesk.com

Comment: No problem, I will send the relevant information